# fix a line for operation on matrices

Tags: matrices, determinant, random-matrices

## operations on matricies determinant

Why does a line at least must be fixed to to operations on matrices for their determinant calculation?

I understand that if it was allowed not to do such a thing any operation could end with a result of zero on its determinant but I don't understand why is it not allowed.

Comment: What do you mean, "at line at least must be fixed"?

Comment: welcome to Mathematics stack exchange, I would suggest you to add an example because it is not very clear the content of your question.